# Blank project in XCode 5 compilation error: Main.Storyboard red in Build Phases

Tags: xcode, ios7, mobile-application, xcode-storyboard, dyld

I'm having big troubles compiling in XCode 5. First of all, I recently upgraded from Xcode 4 to XCode 5 and for some time had both versions intalled. I only have Xcode 5 now (trashed both versions and reinstalled XCode 5 again).
Creating a blank project will not compile showing me the error below:

```
CompileStoryboard test-**/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
cd /Users/user***/test-**/test-**
setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 7.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/user***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-**-czkmrxqmivlfarcpibzviisatxkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test-nogit.app/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc /Users/user***/test-**/test-**/test-**/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard

dyld: Symbol not found: _CGYmageGetRenderingIntent
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 5
```

I am new to the XCode environment, any insights would be very appretiated.
Thanks,

Comment: There's also something else to note. On "Build Phases" under "Copy Bundle Resources" the "MainMenu.xib" (for Mac OS apps) or the "Main.storyboard" (for iOS apps) appear in red.
Removing those files and adding them back will not do, they still appear red.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to add a couple frameworks to your project, starting with the CoreGraphics framework.

Open up the "Frameworks" section of your project and make certain "CoreGraphics" exists, like this:

[image: CoreGraphics goes here]

Comment: Hi, Michael. Thank you very much for your reply. I can tell you that the CoreGraphics framework is included in the Project. It also appears in the "Linked Framework Libraries" with status "required" and not in red.
Being a blank project I don't know why wouldn't such a basic compile won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The clue to resolving this issue was the following line:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _CGYmageGetRenderingIntent
```

The class _CGYmageGetRenderingIntent actually does not exist, it should be _CGImageGetRenderingIntent. So my local XCode library's cache was corrupted at some point either when upgrading OS X or upgrading to Xcode 5.

Had to restart in Safe Mode in order to "flush" the Xcode library's cache.